# Reverse Geocode Here Maps gives error invalid credentials

Tags: maps, credentials, here-api

We are getting error "Invalid credentials for xxxxxxxxxxxx" when I try reverse geocode on Here Maps API.

Even with demo app_id & app_code gives error.

Anyone known a support contact from Here Maps to check out what's going on?

[Edited]
The example request to produce error is: 
https://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&mode=retrieveAddresses&prox=41.8842,-87.6388,250

Answer (score 0):

Working examples using the demo credentials can be found on [developer.here.com](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode)

I guess the issue here is that you are attempting to use the Demo Credentials outside of the examples instead of your own user credentials, and text of the error message is probably deliberately misleading. Try using your own `app_id` and `app_code` instead.

You could also download the Geocoder [Postman Collection](https://github.com/heremaps/postman-collections) to generate proper REST requests rather than relying on a browser.

You could check if the following link works for you.
[https://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=41.8839%2C-87.6389%2C250&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=8&app_id=XXXXXXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXXXX](https://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=41.8839%2C-87.6389%2C250&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=8&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg) - it works for me.